how to implement a master-slave service when using rabbitmq federation plugin
I have a service working in master-slave mode(only master service instance consume message from rabbitmq, and only master service provide service to outside). the master and salve service instance deployed in different zones(each zone deployed a rabbitmq cluster), so i connect the two cluster using federation plugin to handle potential network partition failures.
the queue which master service consume from bind to a topic exchange, other servcie(also deployed in different zones) will products message to the exchange.
I hope the message can be consumed by service only once as much as possible. And when no service instance running , the rabbitmq can store messages wait for service ready. So i must create a queue binding to exchange in each zone.
if i use federation exchange, the master service can consume messages from its queue, but the queue in slave zone will also store messages, and when slave service become master, the same message will be consumed twice.
if i use federation queue,the message can be consumed only once, but one problem is federation queue will not propagate bindings from the downstream to the upstreams. if master service add a binding to exchange, rabbitmq in slave zone don't know the new binding info, and this will cause lose messages.
